# Ruby equivalent call for verifyEditable selenium command

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Using ruby selenium-webdirver, I want to check whether input element is editable or not. To check this, in IDE, we've selenium command - verifyEditable. In Ruby, is there any way(method), we verify whether element is editable?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$driver.find_element(:id, "elementID").enabled?`?  This works as long as you're only checking on an element that you know to be an input field.

In my tests, I just declare a method in the same class/module that hosts the browser control:

```
def element_enabled?(how, what)
  if $driver.find_element(how, what).displayed? && $driver.find_element(how, what).enabled? then
    true
  else
    false
  end
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
  false
end
```

And then you can just use the method with:

```
element_enabled?(:id, "elementID")
```

Having the `foo.displayed? && foo.enabled?` prevents your script from running into errors if the element you're trying to enter input into isn't currently visible.

Including the `rescue` command just makes the method return `false` if you've asked for an element that does not exist on the page.  If you leave out the `rescue` block, your script will exit and return the Selenium error message complaining that the element does not exist.  My preference is to always get a `true` or `false` instead (like with `verifyEditable`), but you may find that you want your script to exit with an error if the element isn't present (like with `assertEditable`).

Answer (score 0):

```
disabled = find('input_id')['disabled']
disabled.should_not == 'disabled'
disabled.should_not == 'true' # just to be safe
```

or with selenium driver you can just go ahead fill it in with some value

```
fill_in 'input_id_or_label', with: "some input value"
```

If the field is disabled selenium will complain (but some headless driver would not, for example [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit)):

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions
```

However I don't think it's a good idea to use selenium to perform such view test -- it's slow and can be flaky, and results may differ from driver to driver. If the view is rendered with input disabled by default, a view test should do the job; otherwise if it's some javascript that disables the input it should be a simple [jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine)/[mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) javascript test.